# How can I get back into "normal" edit-mode after pressing esc in zsh (vi mode)?

Tags: zsh, vi-mode, zle

I'm using `zsh` in `vi-mode`.

When I go to normal mode with <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then back into insert mode (for example using <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>s</kbd>), the line editor kind of "protects" the part of the line in front of the char, at which I was when re-entering insert mode.

I fixed it for the backspace char by rebinding it with

```
bindkey "^?" backward-delete-char
```

But there are still other bindings like `^W` that don't work out of the box (probably because they are bound to `vi-*`).

If I understand it correctly, this behavior is normal to `vi`.

Is there's a way to make `zle` behave like `vim` without having to rebind so many keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICT, the only problematic widgets are:

```
vi-backward-delete-char
vi-kill-line
vi-backward-kill-word
```

So you could do

```
zle -A kill-whole-line vi-kill-line
zle -A backward-kill-word vi-backward-kill-word
zle -A backward-delete-char vi-backward-delete-char
```

Comment: `cntl-u` still seems to be affected by the normal/insert mode switch.